# Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, rxjs

I searched previous threads asking about this error message. From what I can find there are two documented causes for this error message.

1. Missing `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'` or `import 'import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`
2. Error with Visual Studio (which I am not using).

This is the code in question

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Event } from './event';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {

  private eventsUrl = 'api/events'; // URL to web api
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getEvents(): Promise<Event[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.eventsUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Event[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

The code above gives me the error `Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'`

EDIT: Thanks to @estus I found out that I installed one of the packages incorrectly. The package has its own node_modules that also had rxjs resulting in duplicates rxjs inside the project.

Comment: May I ask why are you using "toPromise"? It is not recommended except in the rare case when working with older services that return them. (Which Angular's Http is not one of them.) NOTE: The tutorial at angular.io still has this, but it's currently out of date.

Comment: @DeborahK I see. I am following the toh tutorial which is why it is the case. Thank you for the information. I'll look into what to do with Observable that is returned by Angular Http for the correct way to do it.

Comment: which version of Angular are you using? depending on version, the HTTP response will be handled differently

Comment: You are importing the toPromise method correctly. Maybe this is an editor/ide issue

Comment: I am using Angular 4.4.4 and Sublime Text 3 editor.

Comment: The problem is specific to your case and the way how the app is compiled. It may result from dupe rxjs packages, where toPromise import doesn't affect an observable that is returned from Http. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - a repo or stackblitz.com would be suitable.

Comment: @estus Following your suggestion to scrap everything I found out that the error occurs when I import in-memory-web-api into app.module. The package has its own node_modules and it also has rxjs.  So it turns out I installed in-memory-web-api incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: I also got this same error when I used toPromise in Http service.

Comment: Do you mean the duplicate rxjs or the error message itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @estus. I found out that I installed one of the packages incorrectly. The package has its own node_modules that also had rxjs resulting in duplicates rxjs package inside the project.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to instead follow the updated docs on using the new HttpClient: https://angular.io/guide/http (though they don't have the code in a service).

**Service**

The code in the service would then look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { IMovie } from './movie';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
    private moviesUrl = './api/movies/movies.json';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
        return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl);
    }
}
```

**Component**

And the component code calling this method would look like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.movieService.getMovies()
        .subscribe((movies: IMovie[]) => this.movies = movies);
}
```

Comment: Even though I found out the cause of toPromise acting incorrectly. I will try the up-to-date way to process http requests like you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider importing `Response` from `@angular/http` like this :

```
import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
```

Maybe also upgrading to the latest version of typescript could help:

```
npm i -g typescript@latest
```

A side note also it is better to import Observable alone like this from Rxjs rather than the entire library:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Comment: I tried importing Response and it was the same result.  I had to downgrade typescript to 2.4.0 because of this error `Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.`  I am now trying to get rid of toPromise because according to DeborahK the tutorial is outdated.

Comment: sure no problem, I usually when I answer I don't want to force alternatives and I just stick to the question because other people searching cloud end up here and they just want to solve the issue mentioned in the question title. So it's better to delete this question and have another one if this became irrelevant. By the way did you generate the project with angular cli or clone it from an outdated repo?